# How can you validate a JSON source against a JSON schema?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How can you validate a JSON source against a JSON schema?

The (newly) added [XML format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-xml#xml-as-source) source has got an option for validation against XSD schema

But as far as I can see, the [JSON format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-json#json-as-source) doesn't have an equivalent?

So how can you validate any JSON ?

**EDIT:** *it seems like it's not currently possible, so please vote for this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/41688562-add-a-validation-option-to-the-json-format)*

Comment: like you said, we can't validate the json format in data factory.

Comment: Wow !!! That seems like a bit of an omission

Comment: Hi @Steve, I also think so. Per my experience, it's really a good suggestion for Data Factory to add the JSON format validation.

Comment: Feedback item moved.  It's now @ https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/90bf0f72-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like you said, we can't validate the json format in data factory.

XML format provides the validationMode but JSON format doesn't.
[image]

According my experience, many customers get errors that caused by the invalid JSON format. I usually suggest them using third-part tool to valid its format before copying data.

It's a very good suggestion that I think you can post a feedback. We can help you vote it up that Data Factory product team can see it.

**Update:**
It seems like it's not currently possible, so please vote for this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/41688562-add-a-validation-option-to-the-json-format)
[image]
**Update 2:**
Weird, there are now 6 votes, so is it now available to vote for ?

Comment: Added an item in feedback. Link in my original question.

Comment: Thanks @SteveC. I voted it and add the feedback to my answer. Can you please accept it as answer? More people could see it and this can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Done, and voting now seems to be available

Comment: @SteveC yes, we must sign in and  I voted 3  votes for the feedback.